# ng serve not working in windows

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-start

I did an

```
npm i
npm -g @angular/cli
```

Then when I do

```
ng serve
```

I am getting this error

[image]

But I I put ng serve in npm script (npm start in package.json) it works.

Comment: Try using the command in the root of the project, where the angular-cli file is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install angular-cli and create a project using ng command.

You can follow the steps here

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: If you're using npm > 5 you'd need `npm cache clean -f`

Comment: I had a problem on my Linux,  I followed this and worked on Linux as well, thanks, bro!

Comment: Not worked in this way too :(